# Mysql clustering query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like the following:

```
ID                Output
-------------------------
01ABC1            AB
01ABC2            AB
01ABC3            AB
02ABC1            AC
02ABC2            AC
02ABC3            AB
```

I have to count the number of sets of ID's that has the same first two digits and the output is consistent.
For example in this case
`01ABC1,01ABC2 and 01ABC3` has the same output but `02ABC1,02ABC2 and 02ABC3` does not. 
So the answer will be `1` set.

The output should be

```
ID                Count(ID)
---------------------------    
01ABC            1
02ABC            0
```

Comment: Please post the query you've got so far

Comment: The desired output should be Count(ID) 1

Comment: @AmitBhargava I'll post it in a bit. my actual database is somewhat different from the one I posted here. This is a simpler form of it.

Comment: I am really not getting you.Post your o/p in a tabular format

Comment: what I'm basically struggling is how do I compare multiple rows within the same table

Comment: How about the other IDs.What is your required output for them?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9219/discussion-between-venk-and-ankur)

Comment: Of sorry.. check my updated post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by `consistent` you mean `all the outputs are the same for a given set of ids that share the same first 2 digits`, then this query will do the work:

```
select count(*) from (
    select count(distinct output) aCount from t
    group by left(id, 2)
    having aCount = 1
) final
```

PS: You've edited your question. This answers answer your second edit... the one with this expected result:

```
The output should be
    Count(ID)
    1
```

Comment: MySQL forces you to put a name to a derived table :(

Comment: Whats aCount. I returns no records

Comment: It does. [Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d5a39/5) is an example with your data plus another set of rows that would match, so the result would be 2.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.  If not, I'm sure we can tweak it for you.

```
SELECT count(*) FROM
(
SELECT count(*), digits, Output FROM
(SELECT SUBSTRING(ID, 1, 2) AS digits, Output from `table` GROUP BY 1, 2) AS sub_groups
GROUP BY digits HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
) AS sets
;
```

Answer (score 0):

select id,count(distinct output) ,group_concat(distinct output) from table_name GROUP BY left(id,2).
and output is as you want .Just assume 2 as 0 .